# Reducing width of separation line in memoir Ruled page style

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm writing a thesis template using the memoir class and I like the Ruled page style. According to the class manual:

> This is like the ruled style except that the headers and footers
>   extend into the fore-edge margin.

My question now is: how can I reduce the width of this line? I did not find the answer to this question neither in the manual nor by googling.

This is the (very) simplified page style I want to adopt:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
% Page configuration
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}

\settypeblocksize{7.75in}{32pc}{*}
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.1in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0pt}{0pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{Ruled}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

with

```
\makerunningwidth{Ruled}{\textwidth}
\makeheadrule{Ruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
% Page configuration
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}

\settypeblocksize{7.75in}{32pc}{*}
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.1in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0pt}{0pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout


\makerunningwidth{Ruled}{\textwidth}
\makeheadrule{Ruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{Ruled}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```